# MyISAM table very slow for `count` with `group by`

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, group-by, myisam

The following is my `show create table` for my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tcm_myisam` (
  `time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `asn` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `pop` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `country` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `requests` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `rtt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `rexb` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `nae` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `nf` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `override` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`time`,`asn`,`pop`,`country`),
  KEY `tcm_asn_country_idx` (`asn`,`country`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The table is a log. Every 5 minutes I run a script to add approximately 500,000 rows to this table, with each row uniquely keyed by `(time, asn, pop, country)`. For a given `asn, pop, country` triplet I compute several metrics each time the script runs, then dump these metrics to a table. After appending to the table in this way, the rows are never modified - although I do delete data older than 90 days.

At roughly 500,000 rows per 5 minutes, after a full 90 days we've collected:

```
12 (runs per hour) * 24 (hours) * 90 (days) * 500000 (rows) = 13 BILLION rows
```

Because of the indexes, some (rather complex) queries run incredibly fast despite the large row count:

```
select
    time,
    coalesce(sum(rtt*requests)/sum(requests), 0) as avg_rtt,
    coalesce(sum(rexb*requests)/sum(requests), 0) as avg_rexb,
    coalesce(sum(nae*requests)/sum(requests), 0) as avg_nae,
    coalesce(sum(nf*requests)/sum(requests), 0) as avg_nf,
    coalesce(sum(override*requests)/sum(requests), 0) as avg_override
from
    tcm_myisam
where
    asn = 7018 and
    country = "US"
group by
    time, asn, country
order by time asc;

25920 rows in set, 4012 warnings (15.55 sec)
```

Some queries are even nigh-instantaneous:

```
select distinct(time) from tcm_myisam;

25920 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However this one particular query runs a ***lot*** slower than I think it should:

```
select time, count(*) from tcm_myisam group by time;

25920 rows in set (25 min 55.87 sec)
```

Does anyone know why this is going so slow?

### Update

Below is the `EXPLAIN` for the very slow query:

```
mysql> explain select time, count(*) from tcm_myisam group by time;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows        | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tcm_myisam | NULL       | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 23      | NULL | 13343405769 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------------+----------+-------------+
```

It looks like it's using the index (per the `Using index` bit), but it still runs absurdly slow. Since my primary key's left-most column is `time`, this should be a trivial statement

### Response to @RickJames

**Note:** @RickJames amended his post in response to this. See the "Edit:" portions of his post for details.

Due to the large amount I wanted to post in response, I couldn't fit it into a comment. Therefore I've amended my post with regards to each point you made in your answer.

> Use InnoDB, not MyISAM

I actually have two separate tables as I'm performing an experiment in performance -- `tcm_myisam` and `tcm_innodb`.

That said, the decision to consider MyISAM at all was not a frivolous one. InnoDB provides a **lot** of functionality above and beyond MyISAM, none of which I require:

- **Referential integrity** -- I have no foreign keys in my table
- **Transactions / atomicity** -- I do not utilize transactions, and corrupt data during a failed write will not negatively impact my use case
- **Row-locking** -- There is only one script that writes to the table, the script is never running more than once concurrently, and it only ever appends or deletes rows (never modifies them). Therefore I receive no benefit from row-locking
- **Rollbacks** -- As I do not utilize transactions, I do not utilize this feature

Because MyISAM tables provide a smaller disk footprint (less data to read from disk) and offer a simpler transaction model, there is reduced overhead in queries. The general advice is "if you perform a lot of reads, MyISAM **may** be faster. If you perform a lot of writes, InnoDB is **always** faster". I happen to fall into one of the few use cases where MyISAM outperforms InnoDB.

In my tests the "rather complex" query which aggregates several metrics across all time for a given ASN and country runs in about 15 seconds on MyISAM and about 20 seconds on InnoDB.

> [Get] rid of the secondary index

The only reason this is advised is to "soften the blow" of InnoDB's larger table size. In general if you're grouping or selecting based on a column, it's a good idea to index on it. Telling me to eliminate this index which exactly matches the columns I'm grouping by is asinine.

> Change this [query] to this [query]

I was under the (apparently mistaken) belief that in order to appear in a `where` clause a column must be part of the `group by` clause. However both of the queries executed in an identical amount of time. Your version is only a few characters more terse - for zero performance gain

> And change the indexes to [this order]

The queries I posted here are not the only queries being performed on the data. The most common query run on the data is to return all data for a given time - and therefore it makes sense to have `time` be the first column in my primary index for clustering reasons. I also append all data for a given `time` simultaneously, and perform regular database maintenance to prune all data older than a certain `time`. Since the only writing I do to the database is clustered by time, it makes no sense to cluster the data in any other way.

In fact, the one "absurdly slow" query I posted here was born from this common use case of selecting all data for a given time. I needed to estimate the file size for these time-based groups, so I was figuring out how many rows I had for each time.

By changing my primary key to `(asn, country, time, pop)` it may moderately improve the performance of the "rather complex" query I posted, but it will wreck the performance of most of my other queries

> Are you deliberately using `NULL`?

At metrics collection time, some metrics may not be availble. Either because one of my data sources failed to return data, or because we have no data for a particular ASN+country+pop pair at this time. If we have no data for **any** of the metrics (if we cannot compute `rtt`, `rexb`, `nf`, `nae`, **or** `override`) then we do not insert a row for that ASN+country+pop. However if we have at least one metric (maybe we had sufficient data to compute `rtt` but not enough to compute `nae`) then we fill in the missing columns with `NULL`

If we simply replaced the `NULL` columns with something like `0` then we risk understating our averages

> I don't think `sum(rtt*requests)/sum(rtt)` is "avg_rtt"

Good catch -- this was a typo

> Don't use utf8 for `country`

I actually did not originally specify the charset when creating the table (this was the default assigned by MySQL, and appeared in the output when I typed `show create table tcm_myisam`)

I'll try changing the character set, but I don't anticipate a meaningful change in performance as a result

> **Slow Queries**

This

```
select distinct(time) from tcm_mysiam;
```

took 0.00 seconds because my data is clustered and indexed by time, so it was able to answer the query from the metadata tables instead of performing a table scan

```
select time, count(*) from tcm_myisam group by time;
```

should also be able to use these metadata tables if my understanding is correct - but this did not turn out to be the case

> **Deleting after 90 days**

So far I've only been collecting data since early January, so we don't have a full 90 days of data yet (meaning the "delete" statement hasn't been run on the database before). To test performance once I reach ~13 billion rows I ran a script to generate fake data on a test database.

I was under the impression that by making `time` my primary key (therefore clustering by time) the deletes would be fast. However I will look into partitioning as an additional step to improve performance when the time comes.

> **Summary table**

This summary table already exists. The batch of 500k rows exists so that we can dive into how those summaries were computed.

For instance, if the summary table shows: "India saw a spike in RTT at 5pm three days ago", we can dive into all of the data for India at 5pm three days ago to figure out which ASNs or POPs were affected.

**Addendum:** I currently have two summary tables. One returns the min, max, and weighted average of all metrics per country (rolling up all ASN and POP values). One returns the min, max, and weighted average of all metrics per ASN (rolling up all country and POP values). Effectively these summary tables shrink my keys:

```
(time, asn, country, pop) -> (time, country)
(time, asn, country, pop) -> (time, asn)
```

I am not adding "count of rows" to these summary tables. So by adding that I could get a total count for each time much faster using the summary table than using the original table.

Furthermore I do not have a summary table which returns meaningful data for a given time:

```
(time, asn, country, pop) -> (time)
```

Such a table could not only include "count of rows", but also things like "number of rows which exceeded a certain threshold" or "number of distinct ASNs". So I'll add such a table and adjust my application to read from it where appropriate.

> **Absurdly slow**

I'm well aware that reading **all 13 billion rows** will take time. Even on an M.2 SSD connected to a dedicated PCI-e 3.0x4 line (roughly 32 GB/s of bandwidth) we're looking at 5-8 seconds just to read the primary key from disk.... that's **if** we're reading **all 13 billion rows**

The goal of my indexing is to avoid ever reading all 13 billion rows at once. All 13 billion rows must be available (should we choose to read them), but we only read at most 500,000 rows at a time (when we ask for "all data" for a given time). So instead of reading 13 billion primary keys, we read 26000 "time" keys to filter down the 500,000 rows we actually want, then read those 500,000 rows. A total of 526,000 rows read from disk (index+data) and 5-6 orders of magnitude less disk I/O.

For the most part this works well. I certainly don't have an M.2 SSD on a dedicated PCI-e 3.0x4 line. I've got a crappy platter disk on a shared SATA line which is being simultaneously written to and read from by other applications running on the same machine. I'm lucky to see 50 MB/s read speed. Despite this I see queries completing in under 1 minute (usually).

However the `select time, count(*)` query perplexed me because I thought this would utilize my indexes and instead it scanned the entire table (leading to a 25 **minute** execution time with my crummy disk)

So the crux of my original question, which I'll ask again here, is:

**How do I get a `count(*)` query, when using `group by`, to utilize indexes for performance?**

Note that the simpler query `select count(*) from tcm_myisam` utilizes the table metadata and returns nigh-instantaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema and Query Changes**

Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.  This will cause the disk footprint to increase significantly; below, I recommend getting rid of the secondary index, which will soften the blow.  Still, the footprint may be twice as big.

Edit: Reasons for InnoDB:  (1) Crash safe, (2) efficiency of PK.  Although there is "more overhead" in InnoDB, all the performance improvements in the last decade have been aimed at InnoDB.  So, InnoDB is often as fast or faster, in spite of the "overhead".  I wonder if InnoDB will continue to outperform MyISAM after adding my index suggestions.

Change this

```
where
    asn = 7018 and
    country = "US"
group by
    time, asn, country
order by time asc;
```

to this:

```
WHERE asn = 7018
  AND country = "US"
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time ASC;
```

And change the indexes to

```
PRIMARY KEY(asn, country, time, pop)  -- in this order
```

Edit:  "eliminate this index which exactly matches the columns" -- Since a PK is an index, I did not eliminate the index.  Furthermore, since the PK is "clustered" with the data, *this* query will inherently run faster in InnoDB than MyISAM.  (MyISAM must bounce back and forth between the PK BTree and the data; InnoDB does not need to.)

Edit:  I got rid of `asn` and `country` from the `GROUP BY` so that the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` can be the same, thereby avoiding an extra sort.  (It has nothing to do with the `WHERE`, other than noting that those two columns are tested with `=`, hence irrelevant in the `GROUP BY`.)

Edit:  "The queries I posted here are not the only queries being performed on the data." -- Well, I can't finish helping you until I see them, too.  I have provided advice for the provided queries.  Other queries *may or may not* be *helped or hurt* by my suggestions.

Edit "it makes sense to have time be the first column in my primary index for clustering reasons" -- Yes and No.  'Yes', if the main activity is `INSERTing`.  'No' if the main activity is `SELECTing` and/or if the clustering provides a significant performance boost.

Now `25920 rows in set, 4012 warnings (15.55 sec)` will run significantly faster.  But you should also check the warnings with

```
SHOW WARNINGS LIMIT 20;
```

Are you deliberately using `NULL`?  Or can the columns be `NOT NULL`?  Would the arithmetic be messed up?

I don't think `sum(rtt*requests)/sum(rtt)` is "avg_rtt".  Perhaps divide by `sum(requests)`??

Don't use utf8 for `country`; perhaps not for `pop` either?

Edit:  In some versions/engines, that would take 6 bytes.  Bigger table --> slower queries (somewhat).

**Slow Queries**

This

```
select distinct(time) from tcm_myisam;
```

took 0.00 sec either because of MyISAM, or because you have the Query Cache turned on.  It should probably be turned off since the cash is purged every 5 minutes due to the inserts.

Edit:  I'm curious.  Could you provide `EXPLAIN select ...`.  Also time it with `select SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to avoid the QC.  Possibly there is an optimization for `SELECT DISTINCT` that leapfrogs through the index.

```
select time, count(*) from tcm_myisam group by time;
```

requires a table scan, so it is destined to be slow, and get slower as the table grows.  I'll address a solution later.

**Deleting after 90 days**

Have you tested this?  Have you seen how costly it is?  Let's solve that by `PARTITIONing`.  I suggest `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(time))`.  That would need about 16 partitions.  You would `DROP PARTITION` once a week and `REORGANIZE` once a week.  Details here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

That will make the "delete" instantaneous.  It will slow down the original query some, but I think the tradeoff is worth it.  The reason for the slowdown is having to fetch some rows from each of the 16 partitions.

Edit:  "the deletes would be fast [if `time` is first]" -- it gets more complex than that.  In MyISAM, a giant hole would be carved into the data.  This hole would be filled in by subsequent `INSERTs`, until the next "delete".  Over time, the MyISAM table will get more and more fragmented.  With InnoDB, there would also be a "hole", but essentially no "fragmentation".  In neither case would the table shrink; there would just be free space.  Yes, if the PK *starts* with `time`, the delete will be somewhat faster that with my suggested PK.  However `DROP PARTITION` will be immensely faster than `DELETE`.

Edit: "should also be able to use these metadata tables" -- the only thing approaching "metadata" is MyISAM's keeping the *total* row count.  This is definitely better for `COUNT(*)` with neither `WHERE` nor `GROUP BY`.  But *only for that query*.

Edit: "we read 26000 "time" keys to filter down the 500,000 rows we actually want" -- Note that `PARTITION BY (TO_DAYS(time))` allows for a crude `WHERE time BETWEEN .. AND ..` *in addition to* whatever else is in the `WHERE` (such as `asn`).  That is, Partitioning gives a crude approximation of a 2-dimensional index.  So...  Even though I moved `time` from the start of the PK, you still don't need to read 13 billion rows to get a short time range.  Any query filtering down to under a week will hit only 1 or 2 partitions (depending on alignment of the time range versus the partitions), hence only 1 or 2 billion rows, not 13.

**Summary Table**

Often, in a Data Warehouse situation like this, building and maintaining a "Summary Table" gives a significant performance boost (perhaps 10x).

In your situation, instead of (or in addition to) throwing 500K *raw* rows into the Fact table, summarize them and put them into another table.  Then do the `SELECTs` against that table.

Without understanding why there are 500K rows in every batch, I can't be more specific.

Some generic info on summary tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Edit:  "aggregates several metrics across all time" -- a prime reason for Summary tables.

**Absurdly slow**

13 *billlion* rows (200GB for the PK?) takes time to *read*.  It will be I/O-bound.  My changes will make that query run slower; but is that an important query?  A suitable Summary table can get the counts much faster.

Comment: I've responded to several points you made in my original post, since 500 characters is insufficient to cover everything. There are a few tweaks I'll make to my database per your suggestions (enabling partitioning and changing the charset) however my primary issue was not resolved and some of your suggestions (changing my indexes or switching database engine) are either not helpful or not relevant.

Comment: I responded to most of your comments; see "Edit" paragraphs.  Some my suggestions do not help without other suggestions.  Eg, Changing the PK does not help as much without moving to InnoDB.  Partitioning does more than just help the Delete.  Etc.

Comment: Recreating the tables with partitions and adjusting the indexes improved query performance significantly. Once I got the full 13 billion rows into the databases InnoDB actually read faster than MyISAM after partitioning. As far as the answer to my original question, it's buried deeply within your post (MyISAM is only fast for `count(*)` with no group by, because it keeps the total row count externally -- it does NOT keep a total row count per index key, so `count(*)` with `group by` always requires a table scan). I'll create *another* summary table just to track those counts.